# How to insert Image in a Table?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Management Studio. Is there a way I can insert image in a Column of a Table? Such that, this Column's data would be image. Please suggest me with some SQL Queries.

Thank you

Comment: Varbinary data type.

Comment: http://shortfastcode.blogspot.in/2009/12/insert-binary-data-like-images-into-sql.html

Comment: you can use varBinary(max)

Comment: There are thousands and thousands of example of this all over the internet. While this may be on topic for SO the question is so ambiguous and vague nobody can really offer you a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "varbinary" to store the image into the database. To store the image in database you have to convert the image into Byte and then store it.

Answer (score 0):

insert into YourTableName (YourImageColumnName) 
SELECT BulkColumn
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'imagePathtofile', Single_Blob) as img

MSSQL Server: There is column type, Image which you can use preferably otherwise varbinary. Query is simple, it is reading from file (image and storing binary large object/image into Table. Please let me know if it solves your problem...

Comment: Thanks, what should be this Column datatype?

Comment: But the query is not clear to me. What is BulkColumn and Openrowset here?

Comment: DO NOT use the image datatype. It has been deprecated in favor of varbinary(max) for more than a decade.